# LOAD_FILE doesnt update Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Do I have to save image files to specific location to update MYSQL product image field using `LOAD_FILE`.

I used the following code, First I get `29 rows affected` message but Nothing was updated when i tried again  it using the same statement i get `0 rows affected`

i used

```
        UPDATE ts
        SET product_Image=LOAD_FILE('file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/aaa/xxx/yyy/TM900.jpg')
        WHERE Brand_Name='TM900';
```

I have seen some example and most people use '/tmp/picture/' Is there any specific Location to store Files and use `LOAD_FILE` command?

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess but could your file path be the reason ? try using following file path :

```
UPDATE ts
       SET
product_Image=LOAD_FILE('C:\\Users\user\Desktop\aaa\xxx\yyy\TM900.jpg')
    WHERE Brand_Name='TM900';
```

Update :
login with root user and try this :

```
grant all privileges on *.* to youruser@localhost identified by 'yourpass' with grant option;
flush privileges;
```

Comment: Thanks but No Luck Is there any other way to update Mysql product image?

Comment: ok, the load file function  requires proper file permissions , it could also be the reason

Comment: How can i do that? that's probably the case because i tried it several times

Comment: make sure the file you are loading is on mysqlserver and your mysql user has  file access privilege to it.

Comment: how can i set this privilege? Thanks

Comment: I got this error ` #1045 - Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES) ` i used `grant file on  db.* to 'username'@'host'`

Comment: I used `grant all privileges on *.* to username@mysql-databasename.website.com identified by 'password' with grant option;
flush privileges;` and i get this error message `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-databasename.website.com identified by 'password' with grant option' at line 1 `

Comment: you missed the quotation marks around the database name

Comment: Sorry @thepiyush13 i get  `#1045 - Access denied for user 'password'@'%' (using password: YES)`

Comment: if you are not logged in as the root or admin user, you can not grant permission to other users

Comment: From Cpanel i Grant (checked) all privileges when create the database

Comment: i think that is the root user thats the first user when i create the DB

Comment: thats not enough you need admin user to modify another users access level

Comment: humm what is if i create a new user with all privilages from cpanel and try use `LOAD_FILE`?

Comment: it could work or you could also change the location of the file to mysql bin folder

Comment: i dont think i can do the second option, i dont have access to that